# Laravel error messages for extended custom validator class

Tags: laravel

Here is my validation service provider.

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Services\Validation\CustomValidation;

class ValidationServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        // We don't have to register anything here so we keep this empty!
    }

    /**
     * Boot the service provider.
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        // Need to override the default validator with our own validator
        // We can do that by using the resolver function
        $this->app->validator->resolver(function ($translator, $data, $rules, $messages) {
            // This class will hold all our custom validations
            return new CustomValidation($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the custom validation class that extends Laravel validator class. I am confusing around where should I write my error messages for the custom rule. I could find any documentation for it.

```
<?php namespace App\Services\Validation;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;

class CustomValidation extends Validator
{
    /**
     * $attribute Input name
     * $value Input value
     * $parameters Table, field1
     */
    public function validateCustomRule($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
        // Logic to be written later
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding them to the validation language file using the same convention? `'custom_rule' => 'Some message'`

Comment: @nathanmac, that solved my problem! :) Can you answer, so that i can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding them to the validation language file using the same convention? 'custom_rule' => 'Some message'